# subscription doesn't work properly in zen cart 1.3.8

Tags: php, newsletter, zen-cart

I have got an error in zen cart 1.3.8a. For a registered user, when a user checked it again after unchecked it he/she get an error

```
1062 Duplicate entry 'navido82@hotmail.com' for key 'email_address'
in:
[INSERT INTO subscribers (customers_id, email_address, email_format) VALUES ('2102', 'navido82@hotmail.com', 'HTML')]
```

Comment: I think you should report this as a either a bug or a feature request with the zen-cart project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "subscribers" table in Zen Cart v1.3.8.
So, that's a bug in your own customizations and/or addons.

Furthermore, you REALLY need to upgrade to a secure version of Zen Cart. Your old version is not only obsolete, but has known security problems.

Comment: Sorry, for being late reply... I solved it already... I hard coded on it. Thanks 4 your suggestions.